# Expressing derivative of rotation matrix

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, derivatives

If we have an object with orientation described by 3x3 rotation matrix $R$, we can calculate the derivative of $R$ with respect to time like this:

$$dR/dt = W^*R$$

where $W^*$ is a skew symmetric matrix.

Now however would it be correct to assume that we can also calculate the orientation of an object after time step $t$ like this:

$$R_{t+1} = RW^*$$

If both statements are true then could we derive that:

$$dR/dt = R^TR_{t+1}R$$

Assuming this is true is there an intuitive way to interpret the last statement?

Comment: You can't exactly mix a derivative, which is instantaneous, with a finite time-step for $R_{t+1}$

Comment: @obscurans What if the value of the derivative is constant?